# Existe alguna forma de ejecutar un StoredProcedure definido con SQLServer utilizando python?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.7, sql-server-2017

he utilizado estas librerias, creando un engine y ejecutando como texto la sintaxis de SQL server pero no logro que ejecute el StoredProcedure. Si bien las librerias me sirven para conectarme y realizar consultas a la base de datos, no encuentro la manera de ejecutar este storedProcedure en el servidor para luego consumir la tabla que genera a través de una consulta.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
```

La idea principal es automatizar la corrida des estos procedimientos desde fuera con un script de python.

saludos y gracias desde ya a quien pueda orientarme!!